# Why does an array of characters in C++ return its items instead of its address?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

For instance,

```cpp
const char str[] ={'H','e','l','l','o', '\0'};
const int nums[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
cout << str << " " << nums;
```

gives:

```
Hello 0x7ffff85c0cf5
```

Obviously, if I wanted to get addresses of both, I could do

```cpp
cout << &str << " " << nums
```

But I'm wondering why there's a difference between this array of integers and an array of characters (string literal). Is this a special case preserved only for strings?

Comment: Note that your code has UB, because the character array is not 0-terminated.

Comment: Edited, and will close once 10 minutes mark pass

Comment: Be careful about your wording. An array itself does not _return_ anything. You pass it as an argument to `operator<<` and its different overloads are then chosen in both cases (as explained in the answers).

Comment: @DanielLangr note that not all overloads of `operator<<` are members of the `ostream` class. Many are not. In this case, the `void*` overload is, the `char*` overload is not

Comment: @RemyLebeau I realized that a second after I posted my comment. Edited then. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you're absolutely correct. The `<<` operator on `ostream` has a special overload for a `const char*`.

There's no such overload provided for an `int*` - in that case the `const void*` overload is picked.

Answer (score 1):

There is an overloaded `operator<<` for `const char*`, which your `const char[]` array decays to. This overload treats the `char` data as a null-terminated string, printing out characters until a null character is reached. However, your `char[]` array does not have a null terminator in it. You are lucky you are seeing only `Hello` and not extra garbage, or crashing the app. Your code has *undefined behavior* because of this.

There is no overload of `operator<<` for a `const int[]` array. Your array decays to `const int*`, which is handled by the `operator<<` overload that takes a `const void*` as input, which prints out the address being pointed at.